How do I hide generated files in a PR on GitHub?
When I am about to review a pull request on GitHub, I look at the lines of code changed to get an idea of how time-consuming the review will be.
However, many projects include a bunch of generated files that should not be manually reviewed.

Take this PR for example.
It changes some model implementations that are then generated by freezed, a data class generator.
I only want to review human-written code and trust that the generator output is correct.
Is there any way in GitHub to select which files you want to include in your code review, so that the lines of code to review are updated and reflect the work to be done?

The instinctive (boring) answer I'd give is not to push files to Git (=gitignore) in the first place if they can be generated deterministically, that way they won't show up in changes and code reviews. That might not be an option now though, would filtering by file extension work for your case?

I'm afraid it's not an option.
We continuously re-generate the entire API from an openAPI endpoint, and the project should build and run after downloading it from the repo without needing authentication from the openAPI endpoint.
File extensions will not work since most of the files generated are of the same type as the rest of the project.
We use a .gitatributes file to hide some generated files, but the changed lines still appear in a PR.
I wish the filter files option on GitHub PRs would update the lines, but it does not.

I stumbled on this question looking for the answer myself.
After some research, it looks like GitHub has a way to de-emphasize generated code in PRs by auto-collapsing them using rules you can specify in the .gitattributes file. It doesn't seem like there is a way to exclude it from view completely.
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/customizing-how-changed-files-appear-on-github
From that link:

For example, to mark search/index.json as a generated file, add this line to .gitattributes:

search/index.json linguist-generated=true

